# Como extrair apenas o nome do arquivo sem extensão usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Preciso pegar apenas o nome do aquivo sem a extensão

```
// Aqui está obtendo o nome do arquivo com a extensão. Ex: foto.jpg
//Eu só preciso pegar: "foto"

var filename = $('.upload-image-file').val().split('\\').pop(); 

$('.upload_image').addClass('no-flex');
$('#title').val(filename);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode ser feito combinando o seu método de extração do nome do arquivo com os métodos `substr` e `lastIndexOf`.

---

#### [`String.prototype.substr(*inicio*[, *quantidade*])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Onde:

- *inicio*

É o local para começar a extrair os caracteres. Se um número negativo é passado, é tratado como `strLength - start`, onde `strLength` é o tamanho da string.

- *quantidade*

O número de caracteres a serem extraídos. Se esse argumento for `undefined`, todos os caracteres do `start` ao fim da string serão extraídos.

**Valor de retorno**

Uma nova string contendo a seção extraída da string fornecida. Se o `length` for 0 ou um número negativo, uma string vazia é retornada.

---

#### [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf(*valorBuscado*[, *índice*])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Onde:

- *valorBuscado*

Uma string representado o valor a ser procurado. Se `valorBuscado` for uma string vazia, `índice` é retornado.

- *índice*

O índice no qual a pesquisa será iniciada de trás para frente. Qualquer número inteiro é válido.

---

Nesse exemplo eu fiz uma modificação para permitir que o leitor use o próprio sistema de arquivos como teste. Usei um `<input type="file">` para abrir um diálogo onde podem ser selecionados um ou mais arquivos, então para cada arquivo aplica-se a lógica de buscar todos os caracteres do nome do arquivo com extensão até o último ponto (`lastIndexOf('.')`). Caso o nome do arquivo não tenha extensão só retorna o próprio nome.

```js
function processarArquivo(arquivo){
    // Poderia ser arquivo.mozFullPath.val().split('\\').pop();
    // ou arquivo.webkitFullPath.val().split('\\').pop();
    // mas isso apresenta dois problemas:
    // 1- Só funcionaria No Chrome, Safari e Mozilla. No Opera, Ie e Edge ficariam de fora.
    // 2- Só funcionaria em Windows. Em Linux e MacOsX ficariam de fora.
    // Optei pela solução mais portável que é arquivo.name
    var nomeExt = arquivo.name; 
    
    //Busca todos os caracteres até última ocorrência do ponto(.) se não existir o ponto(.) retorna a própria string.
    var nome = nomeExt.substr(0, nomeExt.lastIndexOf('.')) || nomeExt;
    console.log(nome);
    
}

//Essa função apenas repassa os elementos da fila de arquivos selecionados para o processamento individual
function processarArquivos(e) {
   var arquivos= e.files; 
   for (var i = 0; i < arquivos.length; i++) {
        processarArquivo(arquivos[i]);
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="file" multiple onchange="processarArquivos(this)">      
<div>
```

Comment: Uma ótima resposta. Ainda bem que você usou lasIndexof.

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber o motivo do down vote. Seria bom para o aperfeiçoamento da resposta.

Answer (score -2):

Amigo bom dia !

**bem simples !**

```
$('.upload-image-file').val().split('\\').pop().split('.').shift()
```

**abraço !!**